# PHP 8.1 won't engage

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, installation

I'm on Ubuntu 22.10 and I've done a standard apache and php install with

```
> sudo apt install apache2
```

and the default page appears at 127.0.0.1 on a browser. It works! Then I installed mySQL and starting it works

```
> sudo mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 21
Server version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu2 (Ubuntu)
...
```

then

```
> sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
> php -v
PHP 8.1.7-1ubuntu3.1 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2022 13:39:03) (NTS)
...
```

Now, I create an `info.php`

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

in `/var/www/html/` and try to see it in my browser at 127.0.0.1/info.php and all I get back is the text itself

Obviously php is not engaging. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `127.0.0.1/php.info` is a typo, right?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after installing `libapache2-mod-php`?

Comment: @brombeer Yes! Corrected.

Comment: @brombeer With `sudo service apache2 restart` So I get the spash for apache, but no php stats page.

Comment: Try `apt install php8.1`

Comment: Try `a2enmod php` if `libapache2-mod-php` did not automatically enable the module on installation

Comment: @rickdenhaan So I get `ERROR: Module php does not exist!`

Comment: @brombeer `php8.1 is already the newest version (8.1.7-1ubuntu3.1).`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this post ([ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912638/error-module-php7-0-does-not-exist)) and it works for 8.1. I followed the first, most popular answer (many others were similar) and restarted apache. Success.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me with ubuntu:22.04

```
apt-get update
apt -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-php8.1
```